# Implementing Domain-Specific Resource Files in a ASP.NET Core Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, resx

I'm working on a ASP.NET Core project with resource files organized like this:

```
project/Resources/
- resource.resx
- resource.en.resx
- resource.en-GB.resx
- resource.en-US.resx
```

When the project is built, it generates a class named `resource.Designer.cs` next to the `.resx` file, containing a `ResourceManager` property among others:

```cs
private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;
/// <summary>
/// Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
/// </summary>
[global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
    get {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
            global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("project.Resources.resource", typeof(MyWebApp).Assembly);
            resourceMan = temp;
        }
        return resourceMan;
    }
}
```

In my views, resources are accessed like this:

```html
@using Resource = project.Resources.Resource;

<span>@Resource.WelcomeMessage</span>
```

Now I need to introduce a domain-specific logic, with different resource sets for each domain, superior to the language layer. So, for different domains, the resources would be organized like:

```
project/Resources/Domain1/
- resource.resx
- resource.en.resx
- resource.en-GB.resx
- resource.en-US.resx

project/Resources/Domain2/
- resource.resx
- resource.en.resx
- resource.en-GB.resx
- resource.en-US.resx
```

However, in my views, the reference to the resource class through the Designer.cs files is statically bound to a fixed namespace. This setup does not account for the dynamic nature of selecting resource files based on the current domain.

My goal is finding a way to dynamically adjust this static reference in the views to point to the correct Designer.cs file that corresponds to the specified domain, effectively allowing for domain-specific resources without altering the static access pattern established in the views.

I've also considered renaming the `.resx` files to incorporate the domain directly in their names, like so:

```
project/Resources/
- resource.domain1.resx
- resource.domain1.en.resx
- resource.domain1.en-GB.resx
- resource.domain1.en-US.resx
```

Additionally, I've explored the possibilities offered by `IStringLocalizerFactory` and `IViewLocalizer`. However, both of these solutions seem to require significant changes to the existing resource calling mechanisms in my legacy code, which I'm trying to avoid.

What's the simplest way to support different resource sets based on the domain without modifying the existing access pattern in views?

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: Well, according to your scenario, you could rename the resource files to include the domain name in their filenames and create a custom ResourceManager implementation that dynamically selects the appropriate resource file based on the current domain. This custom implementation replaces the static reference to the ResourceManager generated by the Designer.cs file.

Comment: In addition In views, replace the static reference with calls to the custom ResourceManager implementation, passing the domain name as a parameter to dynamically switch between domains. This approach maintains the static access pattern while enabling domain-specific resource files.

Comment: Is the Designer.cs code generator smart enough to use my custom ResourceManager? The code for the ResourceManager in the generated Designer.cs seems pretty static with a creation of a `System.Resources.ResourceManager temp` instead of relying on some sort of dependency injection